# desplazar caracteres izquierda o derecha en una cadena

Tags: java, string, bucles

Necesito ayuda sobre este ejercicio soy novato en el mundo de la programación. Adjunto la tarea que me han mandado resolver y a continuación el código que e generado yo y que no consigue los resultados que me piden, decir que el desplazamiento no a de ser con arrays. Consigo hacer el desplazamiento pero no que la cadena sea circular (infinita). Entiendo que también, tendría que integrar un bucle para volver al punto de selección de acción (izquierda, derecha, salir), una vez haya efectuado una 1ra vez la acción izquierda o derecha el usuario. no sé solucionar el tema de los desplazamientos ni integrar el bucle. Gracias a todos, un saludo.

[image: Ejercicio planteado]

Código generado por mí:

```
package tareaProg;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class tareaProg1 {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int numero;
        System.out.println ("Introduce un número entero:");
        Scanner entradaNumero=new Scanner (System.in);
        numero=entradaNumero.nextInt ();
        String cadena=Integer.toString(numero);
      
        String[] botones= {"Izquierda", "Derecha", "Salir"};
        int ventana=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog (null, "Escoge una opción:","ACCIONES",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                    botones, botones[0]);
        switch (ventana) {
            case 0:
                {
                    System.out.println ("Número de desplazamientos:");
                    int desplazamiento;
                    Scanner entradaDesplazamiento1=new Scanner (System.in);
                    desplazamiento=entradaDesplazamiento1.nextInt ();
                    int ultimoNumero=cadena.length ();
                    String cadena1=cadena.substring (0,desplazamiento);
                    String cadena2=cadena.substring (desplazamiento++,ultimoNumero++);
                    System.out.println (cadena2 + cadena1);
                    break;
                }
            case 1:
                {
                    System.out.println ("Derecha");
                    System.out.println ("Número de desplazamientos:");
                    int desplazamiento;
                    Scanner entradaDesplazamiento1=new Scanner (System.in);
                    desplazamiento=entradaDesplazamiento1.nextInt ();
                    int ultimoNumero=cadena.length ();
                    String cadena1=cadena.substring (desplazamiento,ultimoNumero);
                    String cadena2=cadena.substring (0,desplazamiento);
                    System.out.println (cadena1 + cadena2);
                    break;
                }
        }
        if (ventana==2){
                    System.out.println ("Salir");
                    System.exit (0);
        }    
       
    }
}
```